# subclassing numpy ndarray to simulate padding with zeros on out of bounds indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to have a 2D numpy array (NxN) which will return zeros when an index is either negative or out of bounds (i.e. I want to suppress the usual wrap-around indexing that occurs when an index is -1 or the IndexError when your index is N). I could do this literally, simply adding a border of zeros around the array and treating it as a 1-based array instead of a 0-based array, but this seems inelegant.

I stumbled across a few answers here relating to subclassing the numpy ndarray class and defining your own `__getitem__` attribute. My first attempt looked like this:

```
import numpy as np

class zeroPaddedArray(np.ndarray):
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        x,y = index
        if x < 0 or y < 0 or x >= self.shape[0] or y >= self.shape[1]:
            return 0
        return super(zeroPaddedArray, self).__getitem__(index)
```

This sort of works, but only allows you to access array elements as `arr[x,y]`, and throws an error when you try `arr[x][y]`. It also completely breaks a lot of other functions such as `print`. `print arr` gives `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`.

My next attempt was to check if a tuple was given for the index, and to default to the old behavior if not.

```
import numpy as np

class zeroPaddedArray(np.ndarray):
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if type(index) is tuple:
            x,y = index
            if x < 0 or y < 0 or x >= self.shape[0] or y >= self.shape[1]:
                return 0
        return super(zeroPaddedArray, self).__getitem__(index)
    else:
        return super(zeroPaddedArray, self).__getitem__(index)
```

This gives me the requires zero-padding behavior when indexing as a tuple (`arr[-1,-1]` correctly gives `0`), but allows other functions to work properly. However, now I get different result depending on the way I index things. For example:

```
a = np.ones((5,5))
b = a.view(zeroPaddedArray)
print b[-1][-1]
print b[-1,-1]
```

gives

```
>>>1.0
>>>0
```

I think this is probably usable as-is for my purposes, but I am unsatisfied. How can I tweak this to give the desired zero-padding behavior regardless of the syntax I use for indexing, without breaking all of the other ndarray functionality?

Comment: Not quite - in the `b[-1][-1]` case `index` is not a tuple, so as I've written it it explcitly uses the old `__getitem__` (the `else` block above). If you try that indixing style on the first example I posted you get an exception, rather than just the default behavior. Thanks for the link, I'll poke through it. And yes, this seems like the sort of hack that is likely to break all kinds of other functionality, so maybe it is simply ill-advised to take this route. I'm open to that as an answer to my question as well ^_^

Comment: Have you looked at `np.take`?

Comment: It looks like a slightly more cumbersome way to do array indexing. Am I missing something? I could use it if the array had zeros all around it to do the same thing, but that would still require me to use it as though it were 1-based. I guess I could use the "raise" mode and catch the exception to return a zero. Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: It looks like take() only works on flattened indices. Not the end of the world, but a bit cumbersome. Is there a way around that besides wrapping it in another function to do the indexing?

Comment: This is my clumsy way to sort slices
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49475674/memmap-array-wrap-custom-type

Answer (score 2):

Here's how `take` could be used:

```
In [34]: a=np.zeros((5,5),int)
In [35]: a[1:4,1:4].flat=np.arange(9)
In [36]: a
Out[36]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 2, 0],
       [0, 3, 4, 5, 0],
       [0, 6, 7, 8, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
In [37]: np.take(a, np.arange(-1,6),1,mode="clip")
Out[37]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 6, 7, 8, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
In [38]: np.take(a, np.arange(-1,6),0,mode="clip")
Out[38]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 2, 0],
       [0, 3, 4, 5, 0],
       [0, 6, 7, 8, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

I'm using the `clip` mode to expand the 0 boundary.

There is also an `np.pad` function, though with all of its generality it is quite long, and no speed solution (it ends up doing 2 concatenates per dimension).

`np.lib.index_tricks.py` has some good examples of using custom classes to playing indexing tricks.

Before getting too deep into subclassing `ndarray` I'd suggest writing functions or trick classes to test your ideas.

Comment: I see how you can get a zero-padded array that way, but that's sort of what I would like to avoid. Unless there is a way to get a reference to a section of a python array that would treat the [0][0] entry of the reference as the [1][1] entry of the parent array, while also making negative indexing simply return values from the border of the parent array instead of looping around?